# Get Hibernate Session from Interceptor

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing a hibernate interceptor and I need to access the hibernate session object. Is their a direct way to access the hibernate session using the interceptor?

What I'm trying to do is to find out what database hibernate has connected to. For various reasons, this is going to be impractical to store as thread local data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems no "official" way of getting hold of the session object neither through `o.h.Interceptor` neither through `o.h.EmptyInterceptor`. Moreover, `Interceptor`'s Javadoc says:

> There might be a single instance of Interceptor for a SessionFactory,
>   or a new instance might be specified for each Session. Whichever
>   approach is used, the interceptor must be serializable if the Session
>   is to be serializable. This means that SessionFactory-scoped
>   interceptors should implement readResolve().
>
> The Session may not be invoked from a callback (nor may a callback
>   cause a collection or proxy to be lazily initialized).

The only way to get this information seems to be by using reflection and has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748933/how-to-get-hibernate-configuration-properties).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way... just pass session to Interceptor after creation:

```
Session session = factory.openSession(interceptor);
interceptor.setSession(session);
```

And you have session inside interceptor! Just remember that:

1. Interceptor can't access session it's running in, so don't use it directly to change / add objects.
2. You can open temporary session on the same JDBC connection
3. Transaction will be the same for both sessions

   ```
   try {    
       Connection connection = mySession.connection();
       Session tempSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(connection); 
       // do something
       tempSession.flush(); 
   } 
   finally { 
       tempSession.close(); 
   }
   ```