# Printing hibernate.jdbc.batch_size

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Is there a way to print the batch_size that was set when configuring the sessionFactory's hibernate properties? For Example, throughout my code I can say:
`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().getTimeout()`

Is there a way to print the batch_size (something like this):

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().getBatchSize()
```

Comment: Using reflection you can get all the properties at run time. Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748933/how-to-get-hibernate-configuration-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Hibernate 5.0 , you can get the hibernate properties using [SessionFactoryOptions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.html) , which can be obtained from `SessionFactory`. No need to use reflection anymore :

```
sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getJdbcBatchSize();
```