# How to check currently set Hibernate settings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

How can I check what hibernate settings are enabled/disabled for my Grails/Spring application? I would like to know also the value of the settings, that I have not specified directly.
My Hibernate config is in yml like:

```yaml
hibernate:
    allow_update_outside_transaction: false
    cache:
        queries: false
        provider_class: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
        region:
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
        use_query_cache: true
        use_second_level_cache: false
```

I tried this: [How to get Hibernate configuration properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748933/how-to-get-hibernate-configuration-properties)
but by doing so, I get to know only the values that I've set directly - e.g. `allow_update_outside_transaction` is disabled by default, but if I don't set it in the `.yml`, I don't see this setting in the `(Properties)f.get(sessionFactory);`

I've also seen this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html
but they don't provide the default values here....

Settings that I'm interested in to check if are enabled or not are especially:

- autocommit
- autoFlush
- open session in view

Comment: Check this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations